# Draw dynamics panels in a windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

Hi currently I have a windows form like this:
[image]

In this form I always have the ten panles and hidde these as acording i need they. For example if I have an object list with seven values ​​I hidde panel 8,9,10 but this way is not eficient because the size of my list always change maybe sometime I will have a list with 13 panels and in this static interface I only hava 10 panels

I want to get better this form. the new windows form is this:
[image]

Now I want to draw the same yellow panels in the right side of the  form but dinamicly acording to the size of my object list something like this
[image]

Comment: Very unclear! What do you mean by 'draw' ?? Really draw or just show?

Comment: Have you at least considered switching to WPF? Before I did I thought it had "a steep learning curve". But it's not true. WPF is indeed easier than WinForms. And when you say "draw" - the WinForms actually draws pixel by pixel. WPF uses DirectX to draw vectors, so it's like "infinitely" faster, plus, the application is DPI aware with minimum effort, that means it works well both on huge 4K TVs and small tablet screens. Plus you can make a "skin" to it, like CSS in web apps.

Comment: When I say draw I refer to put on my table layout panel and my flowlayout panels in execution time.
Put this elements with de code as the same form like first and last picture

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `FlowLayoutPanel` and `TableLayoutPanel`